# How to perform cross-validation of a random-forest model in scikit-learn?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, random-forest, cross-validation

I need to perform leave-one-out cross validation of RF model. 
I successfully built a model with high predictive ability. 
Now I need to perform LOO test prior to the publication.
Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
FC_data = pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\Dre\\Desktop\\My Papers\\Furocoumarins_paper_2018\\Furocoumarins_NEW1.xlsx', index_col=0)
FC_data.head()

# Create correlation matrix
corr_matrix = FC_data.corr().abs()
# Select upper triangle of correlation matrix
upper = corr_matrix.where(np.triu(np.ones(corr_matrix.shape), k=1).astype(np.bool))
# Find index of feature columns with correlation greater than 0.95
to_drop = [column for column in upper.columns if any(upper[column] > 0.95)]
# Drop features 
FC_data1 = FC_data.drop(FC_data[to_drop], axis=1)

y = FC_data1.LogFiT
X = FC_data1.drop(['LogFiT', 'LogS'], axis=1)
X_train = X.drop(["3-Acetoisopseudopsoralen", "3-Carbethoxypsoralen", "4,4'-Dimethylangelicin",
           "4,7,4'-Trimethylallopsoralen", "Psoralen"], axis=0)
X_train.head(21)

y_train = y.drop(["3-Acetoisopseudopsoralen", "3-Carbethoxypsoralen", "4,4'-Dimethylangelicin",
           "4,7,4'-Trimethylallopsoralen", "Psoralen"], axis=0)
y_train.head(21)

X_test = X.loc[["3-Acetoisopseudopsoralen", "3-Carbethoxypsoralen", "4,4'-Dimethylangelicin",
           "4,7,4'-Trimethylallopsoralen", "Psoralen"]]
X_test.head(5)

y_test = y.loc[["3-Acetoisopseudopsoralen", "3-Carbethoxypsoralen", "4,4'-Dimethylangelicin",
           "4,7,4'-Trimethylallopsoralen", "Psoralen"]]
y_test.head(5)

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectFromModel
randomforest = RandomForestRegressor(n_jobs=-1)
selector = SelectFromModel(randomforest)
features_important = selector.fit_transform(X_train, y_train)
model = randomforest.fit(features_important, y_train)

from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
clf_rf = RandomForestRegressor()
parameters = {"n_estimators":[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 10, 15, 20, 30, 40, 50, 100], "max_depth":[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 10, 15, 20, 30, 40, 50, 100]}
grid_search_cv_clf = GridSearchCV(clf_rf, parameters, cv=5)
grid_search_cv_clf.fit(features_important, y_train)

from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
y_pred = grid_search_cv_clf.predict(features_important)
r2_score(y_train, y_pred)

grid_search_cv_clf.best_params_

best_clf = grid_search_cv_clf.best_estimator_
X_test_filtered = X_test.iloc[:,selector.get_support()]
best_clf.score(X_test_filtered, y_test)

feature_importances = best_clf.feature_importances_
feature_importances_df = pd.DataFrame({'features': X_test_filtered.columns.values,
                                  'feature_importances':feature_importances})
importances = feature_importances_df.sort_values('feature_importances', ascending=False)
importances.head(25)
```

Now I need q2 value.

Finally, I wrote this code and got a reasonably high score 0.9071543776303185
.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import LeaveOneOut
parameters = {"n_estimators":[4], "max_depth":[20]}

loo_clf = GridSearchCV(best_clf, parameters, cv=LeaveOneOut())
loo_clf.fit(features_important, y_train)
loo_clf.score(features_important, y_train)
```

I'm not sure if it is q2 or not. How do you think?

I also decided to obtain 5-fold cross-validation score. However, it gives ridiculous values like, for example: -36.58997717,   0.76801832,  -1.59900448,   0.1834304 , -2.38256389 and a mean of -7.924019361863889.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
cvs=cross_val_score(best_clf, features_important, y_train)
mean_cross_val_score = cvs.mean()
mean_cross_val_score
```

Probably, there is a way to fix it?

Comment: what is the `q2` score?

Comment: It's leave-one-out cross-validation score.

Comment: then see my answer below

Answer (score 2):

You should not run the hyper-parameters search before to make the model evaluation. Instead, you should the 2 cross-validations, otherwise, you are leaking some information. To know more about this, you should look at the following example from the scikit-learn documentation: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_nested_cross_validation_iris.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-plot-nested-cross-validation-iris-py

Therefore, in your particular use-case, you should use: GridSearchCV, SelectFromModel, and cross_val_score:

```py
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectFromModel
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.model_selection import LeaveOneOut
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline

X, y = make_regression(n_samples=100)

feature_selector = SelectFromModel(
    RandomForestRegressor(n_jobs=-1), threshold="mean"
)
pipe = make_pipeline(
    feature_selector, RandomForestRegressor(n_jobs=-1)
)

param_grid = {
    # define the grid of the random-forest for the feature selection
    "selectfrommodel__estimator__n_estimators": [10, 20],
    "selectfrommodel__estimator__max_depth": [3, 5],
    # define the grid of the random-forest for the prediction
    "randomforestregressor__n_estimators": [10, 20],
    "randomforestregressor__max_depth": [5, 8],
}
grid_search = GridSearchCV(pipe, param_grid=param_grid, n_jobs=-1, cv=3)
# You can use the LOO in this way. Be aware that this not a good practise,
# it leads to large variance when evaluating your model.
# scores = cross_val_score(pipe, X, y, cv=LeaveOneOut(), error_score='raise')
scores = cross_val_score(pipe, X, y, cv=2, error_score='raise')
score.mean()
```

Answer (score 0):

**You need to specify the `scoring` and the `cv` arguments.**

---

Use this:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score

mycv = LeaveOneOut()
cvs=cross_val_score(best_clf, features_important, y_train, scoring='r2',cv = mycv)

mean_cross_val_score = cvs.mean()
print(mean_cross_val_score)
```

**This will return the mean cross-validated R2 score using LOOCV.**

---

For more scoring options see here: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#common-cases-predefined-values